# Replace squares with \n

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jfilechooser

I have a method to get text from a JTextArea and save in a txt file.
It all works fine but text is saved in a straight line with little empty squares instead of \n.
I would like to replace these squares with \n

My code is:

```
public void createTxt(){

TxtFilter txt = new TxtFilter();

JFileChooser fSave = new JFileChooser();

fSave.setFileFilter(txt);
int result = fSave.showSaveDialog(this);
if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    File sFile = new File(fSave.getSelectedFile()+ ".txt");

    String file_name = sFile.getName();
    String file_path = sFile.getParent();

    try{
         if(!sFile.exists()){

            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sFile));

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(jTextArea1.getText());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String line = "";

            while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
            line = line.replace("o", "\n");
            out.write(line);
            }
            out.close();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Warning file • " + file_name + " • created succesfully in \n" + file_path);    
        }

        else{
```

There must be something wrong because it creates the txt file but it is always empy, no text is get from JTextArea and I always have Exception as from

```
catch(IOException e){
       System.out.println("Error");
   }
```

Where is the error? How to modify the code?

PS I have wrote 'o' instead of empty square because I do not know what to write as first string (or char) to be replaced.

Thanks

Added:PrintStackTrace

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: sdfdsf (Impossibile trovare il file specificato)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
at provegrafica.ProvaFramePop.createTxt(ProvaFramePop.java:154)
at provegrafica.ProvaFramePop.jMenuSaveActionPerformed(ProvaFramePop.java:129)
at provegrafica.ProvaFramePop.access$100(ProvaFramePop.java:17)
at provegrafica.ProvaFramePop$2.actionPerformed(ProvaFramePop.java:64)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:357)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:809)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:850)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6289)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6054)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4652)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:644)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:603)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:601)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:617)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:615)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:614)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 19 seconds)

Added: Else part of the code

```
else{
            String message = "File • " + file_name + " • already exist in \n" + file_path + ":\n" + "Do you want to overwrite?";
            String title = "Warning";
            int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, title, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                sFile.delete();

                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sFile));
                out.write(jTextArea1.getText());
                out.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File • " + file_name + " • overwritten succesfully in \n" + file_path);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Try e.printStackTrace() instead of System.out.println("Error") and then add that to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those *are* \n's.  You are opening in Notepad.

You either need to print out a \r before each \n (which here can be done simply by using a buffered writer which has a printLine method), or open in e.g. Wordpad.

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel.

All text components support a `write(...)` method. This method will use the proper newline string when the text is written to the file. So all you do is:

```
textArea.write(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
line = line.replace("o", "\n");
```

with

```
line = line.replaceAll("o", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: You guys are funny with your down voting... Even if it is not the most optimal solution, it is a right one. So I don't see any reason to down vote my answer. If you think your answer is better leave for the users to decide instead of making it look "better" by down voting other answers.

Comment: This is a question by a beginner. Too many beginners, just copy an answer without thinking. I will downvote any answer where the answer shows a lack of knowledge about the API. I must admit this answer is better than the other one I downvoted because you at least attempt to save the file in the format of the OS. But it is still unnecessary code and not as efficient. Other users could have upvoted your answer if they thought it was the better answer. I had an upvote for the reason I downvoted your answer.

Comment: @camickr _I had an upvote for the reason I downvoted your answer_ - guess by whom :-)

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing in else part
your program is not able to find the specified file.

your condition in if says

```
if(!sFile.exists()){ // don't use not here
// code to write into the file
}
```

where as it should be

```
if(sFile.exists()){
// code to write into the file
}
```

Use following to write to the file

```
while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
        out.append(line); //can also use write in place of append
        out.append("\r\n");
        }
        out.close();
```